# Audience Network - Suspected bundle and placement violations have a limit of 3 appeals

Tags: flutter, facebook-audience-network

I am developing my ios and android applications with audience network ads support using flutter. I released and published both apps in each store successfully. Also, my android version was verified successfully by audience network but the problem is that the iOS version was not approved saying

> our review shows that your app doesn't meet our policy. Check the
> decision details and recommended changes before submitting an appeal
> for us to review the app again.
>
> **Policy violation**
>
> Apps must not spam digital distribution platforms, which includes
> uploading multiple or similar versions of an app. Apps also must not
> omit basic information about the app, such as screenshots of the user
> interface or a description.

Can you show me how to get my ios version approved by the audience network team?

Comment: have fixed the issue? could you please share with us your solution

Comment: No, Facebook doesn't care about our opinion. They just sent the same answers about policy and I couldn't find a solution there. That's why I moved to AdMob.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook don't accept if the icon and the screenshots are not the same as the application , Maybe your icon of the description is modified or contain a word or symbol not really exist in the application.